# Request location updates from background on Android?

Tags: android, service, background, android-workmanager, android-fusedlocation

I would like to implement a tracking app which requests the current user position every 3 minutes. The app should run in background (also when the app is closed). Currently I am trying to use a WorkManager for it. Unfortunately I do not get the GPS position (Toast Message) when the app is closed.

My code:

```
public class LocationWorker extends Worker {
private FusedLocationProviderClient client;

public LocationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    requestLocationUpdates();

    return null;
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
    request.setInterval(5  * 1000);
    request.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
     client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.e("LONG", "location update " + location.getLongitude());
                }

            }
        };
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationCallback,Looper.getMainLooper());

    }
}
```

Any idea what I should do to receive the location updates in background when the app is closed? And should I use WorkManager or is something else a better solution? I also tried the PeriodicWorkRequest but it had a minimum interval (15 min).

Comment: I expect you'd at least need a foreground service to run updates at that frequency

Comment: Check this demo : https://github.com/pratikbutani/LocationTracker-WorkManager/

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593800/1318946

Comment: check this one out. made this a while ago and it worked well at the time: https://gist.github.com/carloscarucce/e809093c0f0bd90e89c86857f823fd9d

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem. I've solved it by using [CoroutineWorker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker) and registering BroadcastReceiver runtime. Here is my solution, I hope it will help.

```kotlin
class LocationUploadWorker(
    private val context: Context,
    params: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    companion object {
        private const val ACTION = "myapp.location"
        private const val TIMEOUT = 60_000L // 1 min
        private const val REQUEST = 1000
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val location = obtain() ?: return Result.retry()
        val result = upload(location)
        return when(result) {
            SuccessResponse -> Result.success()
            ErrorResponse -> Result.failure()
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION])
    private suspend fun obtain(): Location? =
        // coroutines which will cancel all child coroutines if time out reached
        withTimeoutOrNull(TIMEOUT) {
            // this block will suspend until continuation won't be invoked
            suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
                // location client and request
                val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
                val request = LocationRequest().apply { priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY }
                // init intent and receiver
                val intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST, Intent(ACTION), 0)
                val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                    override fun onReceive(context: Context, data: Intent) {
                        val location = LocationResult.extractResult(data)?.lastLocation
                        // stop listening
                        client.removeLocationUpdates(intent)
                        context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                        // resume suspended continuation which basically means return location as function
                        continuation.resume(location)
                    }
                }
                // start listening
                context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(ACTION))
                client.requestLocationUpdates(request, intent)

                // stop listening if cancelled by timeout or other reason
                continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
                    client.removeLocationUpdates(intent)
                    context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
                }
            }
        }
    
    private suspend fun upload(location: Location) {
        // upload your location here
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun Context.startUploadingLocation() {
    if (checkLocationPermissions().not()) return

    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
        .build()

    val request = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<LocationUploadWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .addTag(LocationWorkTag)
        .build()

    WorkManager
        .getInstance(this)
        .enqueue(request)
}
```

```kotlin
fun Context.checkLocationPermissions() =
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out a solution to this problem myself, and so far I discovered that in your case there are a couple of things happening.

First, since API 26, work that happens while your app is in background (or closed for that matter) is throttled down. See here -> [Android Background Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) and also here -> [Android Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) for location in particular.

This means that no matter what, the intervals you added in your solution won't be respected.

The second thing that I believe is happening is that [FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationCallback, looper)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper)) is meant to be used in foreground mode as per documentation. For background mode, it is recommended to use [FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, pendingIntent)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

And this is where my current understanding of using FusedLocationProviderClient (the recommended way of retrieving location) together with WorkManager (the recommended way to executing work in the background) breaks. Because WorkManager is not intended to interoperate with Intents.